# Android Firestore how to get/fetch bunch of boolean value with querydocumentsnapshot for loop?

Tags: android, for-loop, boolean, google-cloud-firestore

I was facing about cannot get the bunch of boolean value from `firestore` in array using for loop.

I wanted to get all the boolean value in a same time using for loop. After I tried I was able to get the boolean with **code below**:

```
    if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {

                        if(!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                            List<Boolean> amenities = new ArrayList<>();
                            for(QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots){
                                amenities.add(queryDocumentSnapshot.getBoolean(Amenity.AIR_CONDITIONER));
                                amenities.add(queryDocumentSnapshot.getBoolean(Amenity.AIR_CONDITIONER));
                                amenities.add(queryDocumentSnapshot.getBoolean(Amenity.BBQ_AREA));
                                amenities.add(queryDocumentSnapshot.getBoolean(Amenity.BBQ_TOOL));
                                amenities.add(queryDocumentSnapshot.getBoolean(Amenity.BATH_TUB));

                            }
                            amenities.size();
                        }
                    }
```

Amenities `size` during debug:

[image]

My firestore structure **image** below :

[image]

How can I make the way by using for loop to get all boolean value in same time?

Comment: What do you mean in the same time? What is wrong with the way you are actually getting those booleans?

Comment: @AlexMamo which mean I no need many of this ` amenities.add(queryDocumentSnapshot.getBoolean(Amenity.AIR_CONDITIONER));` to get the all boolean value because I using class.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand you. What class are you using? Please be more concrete about "get all boolean value in same time". Give us an example to understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method [getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot.html#getData()) on QueryDocumentSnapshot that returns all the fields in the document as a Map.  You can iterate the keys of this map to find all the fields.  For example:

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
    Map<String, Object> data = queryDocumentSnapshot.getData();
    for (String key : data.keySet()) {
        // do something with the key
    }
}
```